# Proof of the Gauss' theorem for electrostatics from Griffiths' book

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, gauss-law

I was looking for a fancy proof of the Gauss' theorem and I found Griffiths' one:
[image]

This is the shortest and the smartest one, but I cannot figure out, in the first part of the derivation, how can he says that the result in (2.12) is valid for "any closed surface", even if he considers only the sphere. How would you prove it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose the charge $q$ is located in the origin. Then the flux of $\vec{E}$ through *any* closed Gaussian surface $\Sigma$ can be represented by the surface integral:

$$\begin{equation}
\Phi=\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\oint_{\Sigma}\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}.d\vec{\sigma} \end{equation}$$

To prove that this integral is independent of the surface $\Sigma$, you need the following theorem, which you can easily verify by a simple calculation or you can find it online.

*Let $S$ be any surface and suppose $S'$ is the projection of $S$ onto the sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, then:*
$$\iint_S\frac{\vec{r}}{r^3}.d\vec{\sigma}=\frac{{area}(S')}{R^2}$$
If you  apply this theorem with $R=1$ to equation one, then the area of $S'$ is that of the entire sphere with $R=1$ and is equal to $4\pi$. Therefor:

$$\Phi=\left(\frac{q}{4\pi\epsilon_0}\right)4\pi=\frac{q}{\varepsilon_0}$$

Note: $\frac{{area}(S')}{R^2}$ is the solid angle of area $S$